# Уникализировать значения выборки msql

Tags: mysql

Имееться таблица допустим:

```
names | folders
------+--------
name1 | folder1
name2 | folder1
name3 | folder1
name4 | folder2
name5 | folder2
name6 | folder2
```

Хочу, чтобы мускул вернул результат **folder1, folder2**, т.е всего 2 значения А как сделать не знаю.... даже не знаю как гугл об этом правильно спросить.

Comment: Ваш вопрос непонятен. Возможно, вы спрашиваете о том, как выбрать конкретные записи по идентификатору. Тогда ответ что-то типа SELECT names, folders FROM table WHERE names = 'name1' or names = 'name2'. Возможно, что вы спрашиваете о том, как ограничить выборку максимум двумя элементами. Тогда ответ что-то типа  SELECT names, folders FROM table LIMIT 0,2 -- но вообще по-хорошему тут нужно условие отбора указать

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы результатом были значения folders. Т.е. может быть folder1, folder2, folder3 и так до бесконечности. Возвращать должно только folder1, folder2, folder3, а не folder1, folder1, folder1, folder2, folder2, folder2, folder3, folder3, folder3, folder3.Т.е. все значения колонки, но уникализированные.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте оператор `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FOLDERS FROM TABLE;
```

Comment: Вот именно то что нужно! Огромное вам спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from `table` GROUP BY `folders`
```